# Throttle all notifications’ sound every 2 minutes

Tags: notifications

I have a lot of notifications on my phone even after I limited it only to the essential ones. I wish I could throttle their sounds every 2 minutes or so. I want notifications to appear on screen in real time but the sound would be played only if there was no other notification sound for these two minutes. Otherwise, just make one sound for all the notifications that arrived during that time. Is there any way to achieve that? I was looking into different apps but no one I could find offers this functionality.

The two minutes used here are just an example.

Kind regards and thank you for your help.